# Calling function within function does not seem to work

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
clubs <- c("AZ","AZ","AZ","AZ")
won <- c("W","L","W","L")
last_match <- c("NA", "NA", "NA","NA")

df_new <- data.frame(clubs, won, last_match)
```

What I would like to do now is:

- read in the csv
- fetch the 2nd till end of rows
- see whether the last match is won

The code below works fine:

```
calc <- function(){

  setwd("...")
  df_new <- read.csv2("df_club.csv", header = T)

  #checking
  print(head(df_new))

  for(i in 2:nrow(df_new)){

   df_new$last_match[i] <-  df_new$won[i-1]
  }

  #checking
  print(head(df_new))

}
```

For overview purposes I would like place the calculate part in a different function however. So thats why I tried this:

```
 #define calculating formule
 calculate_last_win <- function(df){

  for(i in 2:nrow(df_new)){

   df_new$last_match[i] <-  df_new$won[i-1]
  }
  return(df)
 }


#normal function

calc <- function(){

  setwd("...")
  df_new <- read.csv2("df_club.csv", header = T)

  #checking
  print(head(df_new))

  calculate_last_win(df_new)

  #checking
  print(head(df_new))

 }
```

But then my output does not change. Any thoughts on what goes wrong?

Comment: Your `calculate_last_win` function takes `df` as an argument, but then uses `df_new` inside of it. Inside of `calculate_last_win` you should only reference `df`, the data frame passed in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `calc`, replace the line `calculate_last_win(df_new)` by `df_new <- calculate_last_win(df_new)`, and in function `calculate_last_win`, replace `df_new` by `df`.

```
clubs <- c("AZ","AZ","AZ","AZ")
won <- c("W","L","W","L")

dfNew <-data.frame(clubs, won)


#define calculating formule
calculate_last_win <- function(df){

  for(i in 2:nrow(df)){

    df[i,"last_match"] <-  df[i-1,"won"]
  }
  return(df)
}


#normal function

calc <- function(){

  setwd("...")
  df_new <- dfNew

  #checking
  print(head(df_new))

  df_new <- calculate_last_win(df_new)

  #checking
  print(head(df_new))

  return ( df_new )
}
```

.

```
> calc()
  clubs won
1    AZ   W
2    AZ   L
3    AZ   W
4    AZ   L
  clubs won last_match
1    AZ   W       <NA>
2    AZ   L          W
3    AZ   W          L
4    AZ   L          W
  clubs won last_match
1    AZ   W       <NA>
2    AZ   L          W
3    AZ   W          L
4    AZ   L          W
```

Comment: The `apply` can be avoided by just not creating the vector `last_match`. That column will be created automatically inside `calculate_last_win`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function should look like this.  The function needs `df_new` to be `df`.

```
calculate_last_win <- function(df){

  for(i in 2:nrow(df)){

   df$last_match[i] <-  df$won[i-1]
  }
  return(df)
 }
```

I would also check that `return(df)` is replacing `df_new` after the function is called.